# When I commit the changes of my flutter code , does every time new workflow gets created?

Tags: flutter, firebase, github-actions

I have deployed my flutter app on Firebase hosting and linked it with GitHub actions. I want to know that can I use only single workflow ,every time I push code? Because right now every time I commit changes , a new workflow gets created in GitHub actions.

I have deployed my flutter app on Firebase hosting and linked it with GitHub actions. I am expecting to use only a single GitHub workflow every time I commit changes.

Comment: You should post the `worflow` yaml file. Please check that you are using ```on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
``` for triggering the workflow only once for each push event.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a single workflow for all your commits. When you set up github actions
The workflow triggers based on the events specified in **.yml** file on every push to a specified branch. Therefore you don't need to create new workflow for every commit.

Note: just make sure your **.yml** file is configured correctly so that your workflow gets triggered by your commits